# Disable default typescript transformers

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I want to write a custom transpiler using the typescript transformer api that outputs typescript instead of javascript. To accomplish this I would need to disable the default transformers (typescript → ecma2017 → ecma2016 → ...).

Is this possible? I would prefer to use `tsc` directly, but if I have to use the compiler api manually that's fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `ts.ScriptTarget.TypeScript` so you'll need to use the compiler API.

Here's the basic idea (not tested, but should help you start on this):

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

// setup
const printer = ts.createPrinter();
const sourceFiles: ts.SourceFile[] = ...;
const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = ...;

// transform the source files
const transformationResult = ts.transform(sourceFiles, [transformerFactory]);

// log the diagnostics if they exist
if (transformationResult.diagnostics) {
    // output diagnostics (ts.formatDiagnosticsWithColorAndContext is nice to use)
}

// print the transformed ASTs and write the result out to files
// note: replace fs.writeFile with something that actually works
const fileWrites = transformationResult.transformed
    .map(file => fs.writeFile(file.fileName, printer.printFile(file));
Promise.all(fileWrites)
    .then(() => console.log("finished"))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```