# TypeScript compiler API apply default/built-in transforms for CompilerOptions to AST

Tags: typescript, cross-browser, typescript-compiler-api

I'd like to make a compatibility checker like [`eslint-plugin-compat`](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat) but for TypeScript, such that it is more reliable because I have access to the types of variables. Basically, what I'd like to do is check things like the use of certain functions & syntax and check if it is compatible with certain browsers. This seems not too hard, especially when using [`ts-morph`](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/ts-morph), but there is a problem I run into: TypeScript can transform a lot of syntax & builtin function calls so that it is supported by older browsers by setting the `target` compiler option to something like `ES2015`, so when I use a feature that may not be supported by some browsers, maybe in the resulting JS the function is not used after all, so no warning should be generated. Now this is great, but the syntax tree (AST) I get with the compiler API / ts-morph is not transformed in this way yet, so my tool would think that some feature is used while in the resulting JS it is not.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907240/4454665) discussing custom transforms, but I want to execute the *built-in* transformers (given the target etc.). I located the code that decides which transformers to apply in the TypeScript source code in [`compiler/transformer.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/transformer.ts) and e.g. the transformer for ES2015 in [`compiler/transformers/es2015.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/transformers/es2015.ts). The problem is now that all these functions are for marked internal use only.

So my question is: **How can I still execute my analysis code on the transformed AST?** Is there even a way to do this without copying the transformer code or using internal functions? (Btw: I briefly tried the latter but actually couldn't get it to work)

Comment: I don't know how this would play out with `ts-morph`, but the "vanilla` `ts.emit` function allows specifying an "`after`" transformer ([reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7cf4b12d8835ebaf590d8a29a23290500c756fec/lib/typescript.d.ts#L1988-L1995))

Comment: @superbadcodemonkey Oh hmm. Are types still available there? Because then this might be an option!

Comment: Good point, I think you just get the (untyped) JavaScript AST, but I've never used an `after` transformer so I'm not sure.